# jQuery Ajax call with no results expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I'm trying to collect some stats on some clicking events happening on my webpage.

I figured I would add an onmouse event to the links I want to track, and trigger an ajax call to my tracking php script.

What would be the most efficient way to do that, knowing that I don't expect anything in return, and that things should go on normally even if it fails?

I know there are some special HTTP calls when you don't expect any data back. What is it exactly? Does jQuery support it? What about my php script, should it return a special HTTP header?

Any advice to make this efficient is welcomed.

Thanks

Nathan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could send a `204 no content`. Google seem to do it on their home page for  <strike>exactly the same purpose</strike> for making the client look up a DNS entry faster.

See this SO question about how Google uses it: [**Google.com and clients1.google.com/generate_204**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989214/google-com-and-clients1-google-com-generate204)

And the [**Status Code Definition**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) sounds about right:

> **10.2.5 204 No Content**
>
> The server has fulfilled the request
> but does not need to return an
> entity-body, and might want to return
> updated metainformation. The response
> MAY include new or updated
> metainformation in the form of
> entity-headers, which if present
> SHOULD be associated with the
> requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it
> SHOULD NOT change its document view
> from that which caused the request to
> be sent. This response is primarily
> intended to allow input for actions to
> take place without causing a change to
> the user agent's active document view,
> although any new or updated
> metainformation SHOULD be applied to
> the document currently in the user
> agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a
> message-body, and thus is always
> terminated by the first empty line
> after the header fields.

Comment: good stuff. What about the jQuery Ajax call itself? Is GET the best there is? Or can we do a HEAD or something like that? Or is it worth it?

Comment: Good question. I don't know 100% but a GET should be sufficient (I've never seen a HEAD call in Ajax). With a 204, the response body would be empty anyway.