# HTTP 204 (no content) when triggering onLoad and onError for an Image?

Tags: javascript, http, cross-browser

Does every browser behave consistently when getting a HTTP "204 No Content" for an img src request?

```
<img src="/gives_me_a_204.gif" onError="alert('err')" onLoad="alert('ok')" />
```

on firefox and opera i get an 'err', want to know if all others browsers will also give me that.

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't count on it. Then again, IIRC Google uses it for their tracking pixels. Maybe expand on your real world use case?

Comment: Indeed, I remembered correctly. Related:  [Google.com and clients1.google.com/generate_204](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1989214)

Comment: @Pekka I looked at gmaps code, the image there is used only generate a DNS cache of the domain, so that there's no delay when they send the ajax one. I don't think they use image's onload/onerror for the beacons itself.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think you should add some more detail about what you are doing, and what behaviour you are expecting. I'm not sure how `onError` would come into play at all when a 204 is served? Either way, this sounds like such an edge case that you probably won't be able to rely on the same behaviour across browsers. But maybe somebody can suggest a workaround for whatever it is you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is required by the HTML specification.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#updating-the-image-data

> **Otherwise**
>
> The image data is not in a supported file format; the user agent must set image request's state to broken, abort the image request for
> the current request and the pending request, upgrade the pending
> request to the current request if image request is the pending
> request, and then queue an element task on the DOM manipulation task
> source given the img element to finalize image loading with error.