# App keeps pinging clients3.google.com/generate_204

Tags: android

Any ideas why my app keeps pinging this url: `http://clients3.google.com/generate_204` ?

I don't do anything in the app, just keep it open and it keeps pinging that link every second or so. I doesn't matter in what screen I'm in, it keeps doing it.

Any ideas on where this comes from, why and how to stop it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe something from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989214/google-com-and-clients1-google-com-generate-204

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: That is the way it checks the internet connection. Are you using any google libraries? (firebase, play services, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, all of the above :). But still ... that's a ton of pings aren't there? I've checked one of my other apps, they don't do this.

Comment: it *probably* uses other set of google services, or other version of them.

Answer (score 7):

It generally means you are using some library that is checking the Internet connectivity and this URL is the best option to ping as it should work 24/7 without maintenance pause.
It doesn't have to be only Google libraries. For example here React Native NetInfo library, the `reachabilityUrl` URL here: https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/blob/2f0c8b9e5c09d23472e5d9f7d9bd1d8555698202/README.md#netinfoconfiguration